# Channel Factory vs Service Proxy

Tags: performance, wcf, wcf-binding

When to use Channel Factory, and When to use Service Proxy in WCF?

My binding is NetNamedPipeBinding. and I'm planning to use a Duplex connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel Factory and Service Proxy are equal features for getting one aim - consume you service. Usually if you control service contract interface both on you client and server, you'd better use ChannelFactory, because it is managed more easier. If you manage only client part - Proxy is a way to go, because othewise you would not be able to control the changes, made on the server side. Besides Proxy gives you a nice tool of generating async methods for your service :)

Comment: and what's the better choice in case of Duplex connection?

Comment: @m.samy Duplex (and NetNamedPipeBinding) usually means, that you manage both client and server. In your case i would choose ChannelFactory.

Answer (score 2):

**When to use a proxy?**

We create proxy using svcutil.exe. The output of this tool gives a proxy class and makes corresponding changes to the application configuration file. If you have a service that you know is going to be used by several applications or is generic enough to be used in several places, you'll want to continue using the generated proxy classes. We use proxy in WCF to be able to share the service contract and entities with the client. Proxies have several restrictions like they need to have gets and sets , contructors can't be exposed , methods other than the service contract cannot be exposed, repetition of code, everytime that we add/modify a service contract/data contract/message contract we need to re-generate the proxy for the client.

**When to use ChannelFactory**

The other option is  using the ChannelFactory class to construct a channel between the client and the service without the need of a proxy . In some cases, you may have a service that is tightly bound to the client application. In such a case, it makes sense to reference the Interface DLL directly and use ChannelFactory to call your methods using that. One significant advantage of the ChannelFactory route is that it gives you access to methods that wouldn't otherwise be available if you used svcutil.exe..

**When to use a ChannelFactory vs Proxy class?**

A DLL is helpful if the client code is under you control and you'd like to  share more than just the service contract with the client -- such as some utility methods associated with entities and make the client & the service code more tightly bound. If you know that your entities will not change much and the client code is less, then a DLL would work better than a proxy. If the client to your service is external to the system, such as API, it makes sense to use a proxy, because it makes sharing the contract easier by giving a code file rather than a DLL.

**In case of NetNamedPipeBinding**

It's recommended to use ChannelFactory for the following two reasons:

1. The easy of use.
2. avoiding the proxy layer means extra performance.